# Changing color of Twitter bootstrap Nav-Pills

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, nav, nav-pills

I'm trying to change the active color (after its clicked it remains twitter's light-blue color) for each tab:

```
 <ul class="nav nav-pills">
   <li class="active"><a href="#tab1" data-toggle="tab">Overview</a></li>
   <li><a href="#tab2" data-toggle="tab">Sample</a></li>
   <li><a href="#tab3" data-toggle="tab">Sample</a></li>
 </ul>
```

(How) can I do this in CSS?

Comment: Manipulate color how? you mean change the blue to something else?

Comment: Hi Andres, yes, change the color to something else...

Answer (score 102, accepted):

You can supply your own class to the `nav-pills` container with your custom color for your active link, that way you can create as many colors as you like without modifying the bootstrap default colors in other sections of your page. Try this:

**Markup**

```
<ul class="nav nav-pills red">
    <li class="active"><a href="#tab1" data-toggle="tab">Overview</a></li>
    <li><a href="#tab2" data-toggle="tab">Sample</a></li>
    <li><a href="#tab3" data-toggle="tab">Sample</a></li>
</ul>
```

And here is the CSS for your custom color:

```
.red .active a,
.red .active a:hover {
    background-color: red;
}
```

Also, if you prefer to replace the default color for the `.active` item in your `nav-pills` you can modify the original like so:

```
.nav-pills > .active > a, .nav-pills > .active > a:hover {
    background-color: red;
}
```

Comment: You also have to add `.nav-pills > .active > a:focus` to that list in the CSS file, to make sure the color stays the same even when you click on the navpill.

Comment: @raffian In 3.X you have to be more specific, for the last example: `.nav-pills > li.active > a, .nav-pills > li.active > a:hover` - bootstrap CSS specifies `li.active` now, not only `.active`

Comment: This didn't work for me directly, I had to add !important to the background color.

Answer (score 43):

The most voted solution did not work for me.**(Bootstrap 3.0.0)** However, this did:

```
.nav-pills > li.active > a, .nav-pills > li.active > a:hover, .nav-pills > li.active > a:focus {
    color:black;
    background-color:#fcd900;
    }
```

including this on the page `<style></style>` tags serves for the per page basis well

and mixing it on two shades gives a brilliant effect like:

```
<style>
    .nav-pills > li.active > a, .nav-pills > li.active > a:focus {
        color: black;
        background-color: #fcd900;
    }

        .nav-pills > li.active > a:hover {
            background-color: #efcb00;
            color:black;
        }
</style>
```

Comment: Thanks this worked for me too...should be marked as correct answer!

Answer (score 20):

For Bootstrap 4.0 (in alpha as of the moment of typing) you should specify the `.active` class on the `a` element.

For me only the following worked:

```
.nav-pills > li > a.active {
    background-color: #ff0000 !important;
}
```

The `!important` was also necessary.

--

Edit: added space before the `!important` according to comment below by CodeMantle

Comment: This won't work in Firefox as written. It needs a space before the `!important;`

Answer (score 14):

#### Bootstrap 4.x Solution

```
.nav-pills .nav-link.active {
    background-color: #ff0000 !important;
}
```

Comment: This works on Chrome 88, but does not work as written on Firefox 85. It needs to have a space before the `!important;`

Answer (score 7):

This is specific to Bootstrap 4.0.

**HTML**

```
<ul class="nav nav-pills">
  <li class="nav-item">
    <a class="nav-link nav-link-color" href="#about">home</a>
  </li>
  <li class="nav-item">
    <a class="nav-link nav-link-color"  href="#contact">contact</a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

**CSS**

```
.nav-pills > li > a.active {
  background-color: #ffffff !important;
  color: #ffffff !important;
}

.nav-pills > li > a:hover {
  color: #ffffff !important;
}

.nav-link-color {
  color: #ffffff;
}
```

Comment: Hi @sam-sokeye, I think the top answer may already be working for Bootstrap 4.

Answer (score 5):

**On Bootstrap 5.0.x :**

```
<style>
    .nav-pills .nav-link.active, .nav-pills .show>.nav-link {
        color: #fff;
        background-color: #af2e89;
    }
</style>
```

Answer (score 3):

I use this snipped to change the active class for all pills in the same ul (applied at document ready):

```
$('ul.nav.nav-pills li a').click(function() {           
    $(this).parent().addClass('active').siblings().removeClass('active');           
});
```

Answer (score 3):

If you don't want to include any extra CSS you can just use the button color classes into the nav-link element, it will format the pill just the same as a regular button.

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.min.js" integrity="sha256-CSXorXvZcTkaix6Yvo6HppcZGetbYMGWSFlBw8HfCJo=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JjSmVgyd0p3pXB1rRibZUAYoIIy6OrQ6VrjIEaFf/nJGzIxFDsf4x0xIM+B07jRM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<ul class="nav nav-pills p-3">
    <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link active" href="#">Normal</a>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link active btn-primary" href="#">Primary</a>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link active btn-secondary" href="#">Secondary</a>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link active btn-success" href="#">Success</a>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link active btn-warning" href="#">Warning</a>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link active btn-danger" href="#">Danger</a>
    </li>

</ul>
```

Answer (score 2):

The following code worked for me:-

```
.nav-pills .nav-link.active, .nav-pills .show>.nav-link {
    color: #fff;
    background-color: rgba(0,123,255,.5);
}
```

Note:- This worked for me using Bootstrap 4

Answer (score 1):

SCSS option for changing all of the buttons...

```
// do something for each color
@each $color, $value in $theme-colors {

  // nav-link outline colors on the outer nav element
  .nav-outline-#{$color} .nav-link {
    @include button-outline-variant($value);
    margin: 2px 0;
  }

  // nav-link colors on the outer nav element
  .nav-#{$color} .nav-link {
    @include button-variant($value, $value);
    margin: 2px 0;
  }
}
```

so you end up with all the defined colors `.nav-primary`
similar to the `.btn-primary`...

```
<div class="col-2 nav-secondary">
            <div class="nav flex-column nav-pills" id="v-pills-tab" role="tablist" aria-orientation="vertical">
                <a class="nav-link" aria-expanded="true" aria-controls="addService" data-toggle="pill" href="#addService" role="tab" aria-selected="false">
                    Add Service
                </a>
                <a class="nav-link" aria-expanded="true" aria-controls="bonusPayment" data-toggle="pill" href="#bonusPayment" role="tab" aria-selected="false">
                    Bonus Payment
                </a>
                <a class="nav-link" aria-expanded="true" aria-controls="oneTimeInvoice" data-toggle="pill" href="#oneTimeInvoice" role="tab" aria-selected="false">
                    Invoice - One Time
                </a>
                <a class="nav-link active" aria-expanded="true" aria-controls="oneTimePayment" data-toggle="pill" href="#oneTimePayment" role="tab" aria-selected="true">
                    Payment - One Time
                </a>
            </div>
        </div>
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Step 1: Define a class named `applycolor` which can be used to apply the color you choose.

Step 2: Define what actions happens to it when it hovers. If your form background is white, then you must make sure that on hover the tab does not turn white. To achieve this use the `!important` clause to force this feature on hover property. We are doing this to override Bootstrap's default behavior.

Step 3: Apply the class to the Tabs which you are targetting.

**CSS section:**

```
<style>
    .nav-pills > li.active > a, .nav-pills > li.active > a:hover, .nav-pills > li.active > a:focus {
        color: #fff;
        background-color: #337ab7 !important;
    }

    .nav > li > a:hover, .nav > li > a:focus {
        text-decoration: none;
        background-color: none !important;
    }

    .applycolor {
        background-color: #efefef;
        text-decoration: none;
        color: #fff;
    }

    .applycolor:hover {
        background-color: #337ab7;
        text-decoration: none;
        color: #fff;
    }
</style>
```

**Tab Section :**

```
<section class="form-toolbar row">
    <div class="form-title col-sm-12" id="tabs">
        <ul class="nav nav-pills nav-justified">
            <li class="applycolor"><a data-toggle="pill" href="#instance" style="font-size: 1.8rem; font-weight: 800;">My Apps</a></li>
            <li class="active applycolor"><a data-toggle="pill" href="#application" style="font-size: 1.8rem; font-weight: 800;">Apps Collection</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</section>
```

Answer (score 0):

The Solution to this problem, tends to differ slightly from case to case.
The general  way to solve it is to 
1.) right-click the bootstrap pill and select inspect or inspect element if firefox
2.) copy the css selector for the rule that changes the color
3.) modify it in your custom css file like so...

```
.TheCssSelectorYouJustCopied{
    background-color: #ff0000!important;//or any other color
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me perfectly in bootstrap 4.4.1 !!

```
.nav-pills > li > a.active{
  background-color:#46b3e6 !important;
  color:white !important;
}

  .nav-pills > li.active > a:hover {
  background-color:#46b3e6 !important;
  color:white !important;
        }

.nav-link-color {
  color: #46b3e6;
}
```

Comment: there is no nav-link-color in 4.4.x

Answer (score 0):

that's worked for me Bootstrap v3.3.7
write that in your css file!

```
.nav > li > a:hover,
.nav > li > a:focus {
   text-decoration: none;
   background-color: #0d0d0d;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

### Bootstrap 5.x Dynamique Solution

from standard exemple just add the following html & css
**btn btn-*color-class***
i add "[data-bs-target]" not to interfere with nav-link from navbar

```css
.nav-link[data-bs-target] {
}
.nav-link[data-bs-target]:hover {
    color: var(--bs-btn-hover-color);
    background-color: var(--bs-btn-hover-bg);
    border-color: var(--bs-btn-hover-border-color);
}
.nav-link[data-bs-target].active {
    color: var(--bs-btn-hover-color);
    background-color: var(--bs-btn-hover-bg);
    border-color: var(--bs-btn-hover-border-color);
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.2/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
<nav>
    <div class="nav nav-tabs" id="nav-tab" role="tablist">
        <button class="nav-link btn btn-primary active" id="nav-home-tab" data-bs-toggle="tab" data-bs-target="#nav-home" type="button" role="tab" aria-controls="nav-home" aria-selected="true">Home</button>
        <button class="nav-link btn btn-info" id="nav-profile-tab" data-bs-toggle="tab" data-bs-target="#nav-profile" type="button" role="tab" aria-controls="nav-profile" aria-selected="false">Profile</button>
        <button class="nav-link btn btn-danger" id="nav-contact-tab" data-bs-toggle="tab" data-bs-target="#nav-contact" type="button" role="tab" aria-controls="nav-contact" aria-selected="false">Contact</button>
        <button class="nav-link btn btn-success" id="nav-disabled-tab" data-bs-toggle="tab" data-bs-target="#nav-disabled" type="button" role="tab" aria-controls="nav-disabled" aria-selected="false" disabled>Disabled</button>
    </div>
</nav>
    <div class="tab-content" id="nav-tabContent">
    <div class="tab-pane fade show active" id="nav-home" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="nav-home-tab" tabindex="0">...</div>
    <div class="tab-pane fade" id="nav-profile" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="nav-profile-tab" tabindex="0">...</div>
    <div class="tab-pane fade" id="nav-contact" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="nav-contact-tab" tabindex="0">...</div>
    <div class="tab-pane fade" id="nav-disabled" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="nav-disabled-tab" tabindex="0">...</div>
</div>
```