# How can I have more control over the table of contents in R Markdown?

Tags: r, r-markdown, tableofcontents

I'm working in a project with R Markdown to automate some report of the company I work for.
Recently, I discovered that we can add the option `toc: true` to show the table of contents based on headings. 
It worked very well and I also set the option `toc_float: true` to display the toc on the left side of display.
My question, does anyone know how to have more control over this table of contents, like change colors, the visual and other kinds of stuff?

Comment: (1) It depends, what's your output format? `toc` applies to multiple formats, and styling is likely different for each. (2) It always helps when you can provide a concrete minimal example to play with. It doesn't have to be huge or complex, just enough to trigger a few key features you need to get your point across. Refs: https://stackoverflow.com/q/5963269, [mcve], and https://stackoverflow.com/tags/r/info.

Comment: The first answer to this stackoverflow question has a lot of info about changing the CSS of an HTML R Markdown! https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42546001/how-to-change-colors-and-attributes-of-table-of-contents-in-r-markdown-html-docu

Comment: @r2evans sorry, I forgot to tell about the output, which is html by the way. I can't provide a minimal exemple because the document has more than 3000 rows of code. I was just wondering if there is any library to style TOC.